# FastApi when declaring my Columns during run-time, such as "String"

Tags: python, types, sqlalchemy, casting, fastapi

I want to be able to create a Column with the type "String" without explicitly writing sqlalchemy.String because the type will depend on user input, and the type is decided by the user. Is there any way I could cast this String into an SQLAlchemy.String type?

```
Table("table_name",
    metadata,
    Column("Id", Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column("label_name", "String"),
)
```

Comment: You can't have different column types per row in an RDBMS, if that's what you're asking. If you want to have a mapping where someone can configure their own tables through a function, use a lookup table from your keywords to the type they define (i.e. `{"String": sqlalchemy.String)`. Another option would be to look up `String` dynamically in the module, but you probably want to make sure that the type they give is a valid SQLAlchemy type (and not a different part of SQLAlchemy).

Comment: Thank you, yea that worked! I have an enum that checks the user input and I have a dictionary that maps it to the corresponding sqlalchemy type.